# FileNameExtensionFilter is not working in a loop?

Tags: java, filter

I got the following code from BorisTheSpider (thank him, the loop works perfect):

```
final FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("pdf");
        final File path = new File (pathToFiles);
        for (final File child: path.listFiles()) {
            if (filter.accept(child)) {
            claimArrayList.add(child.getName());
            System.out.println(child.getName());
            }
        }
```

But I get the following exception for the FileNameExtensionFilter

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Extensions must be non-null and not empty
```

Then I tried

`i tried final FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, "pdf");`

Although it filters pdf files it also allows for subfolders

When I try to add other arguments, the filter allows for all files

```
 final FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("csv", "pdf");
```

Comment: The constructor for that class is incredibly stupid, uses varargs but throws exception if it's empty.

Comment: You need to read the description. The first parameter is a description `String`, _then_ the file extensions follow.

Comment: I need to use only pdf extension files ... how can i do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not passing the correct arguments to the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html#FileNameExtensionFilter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29). Specifically, you are missing the first argument, `description`.

It is permissible for the description to be `null`, so if you don't have anything better to put there you could just use

```
final FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, "pdf");
```

Comment: He's missing or he's supplying (in his first example)?

Comment: i tried `final FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, "pdf");` it this case it filters pdfs. But it allows for the subfolders

Comment: Check if it `isFile()` or not.

Answer (score 3):

Be *cool*, use **Java 7 NIO** classes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.pdf");
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> files = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/"),
        new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
                return pathMatcher.matches(entry); 
            }
        })
    ) {

        for (Path path : files) {
            System.out.println(path.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I'm not answering the question, just proposing an alternative. See all the other answers for correct usage of `FileNameExtensionFilter`.

The Java 7 NIO package has much more utility than the old `java.io`. Use it to your advantage.

Answer (score 3):

The [`FileNameExtensionFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) class is intended for [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) to be used in a [`JFileChooser`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

If you're not using Swing then [`FilenameFilter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) is typically used to filter files. For example:

```
File dir = new File("/path/to/dirname");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[`FileNameExtensionFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html#FileNameExtensionFilter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) accepts, at least, two `String` parameters, a description and a variable list of extensions that the filter can match...

For example...

```
final FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Portable Document Format (*.PDF)", "pdf");
final File path = new File(pathToFiles);
for (final File child : path.listFiles()) {
    if (filter.accept(child)) {
        claimArrayList.add(child.getName());
        System.out.println(child.getName());
    }
}
```

An alternative approach would be to use something like a [`FileFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) directly with the `listFiles` method, for example...

```
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf");
    }
};
final File path = new File(pathToFiles);
File[] acceptableFiles = path.listFiles(filter);
claimArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(acceptableFiles));
```

While both approaches are valid and have their good and bad points, the reason I (personally) prefer the second approach is `listFiles` has already scanned the entire directory gathering the file list.  Then you do another loop to filter it.

The second approach is more efficient in that it filters the list AS it's being generated.  While the performance is probably arguable on a small directory listing, when you start dealing with directories containing many hundreds of files, anything you can do make it more efficient is going to help - IMHO